# how to place elements inside divs horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want the elements inside the div to be placed horizontally .

here is my small code

```
<div>
    <g:Label>Legal Name </g:Label>
    <g:TextBox> </g:TextBox>
</div>
```

I have these 2 elements in my div , I want to place them in one row ,but I am getting a label then in the next row I am getting the textbox , Any idea how to make both in one line.

disply:inline  works .. but

isn't this possible ..?

```
            <div className="test">

    <g:Label>Legal Name </g:Label>
    <g:TextBox ui:field="txtLegalName"></g:TextBox>

    </div>
```

css:

```
   .test{
display:inline-block;
```

}

I actually want to reduce my code , don't want to put this style to every widget of the Div, as there will be many elements coming into this div

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define **float** or **display:inline-block** to it. Write like this:

```
label,input{display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you require that the elements are in one row, then you'll need to force the parent not to wrap the lines, using the CSS `white-space` property:

```
parentElementSelector {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

parentElementSelector childElements {
    display: inline;
    /* or:
    display: inline-block;
    */
}
```

If you use only the `display` property the elements will wrap when they come to the end of the line within their parent container, whereas the `nowrap` forces the line to continue. You may also wish to specify an `overflow` behaviour for the parent element (`hidden`, `overflow-x` and so forth) depending on your design/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` and `float:right` property.

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/suw8R/4/

Answer (score -1):

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
    <g:Label>Legal Name </g:Label>
    <g:TextBox> </g:TextBox>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```